# How to transfer this to a data set I need?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-entry

```
[1] 1 6 6 6 1 6 5 1 5 1 1 6 4 5 5 3 6 3 4 4 3 4 3 1 5 5 6 2 4 3 6 6 2 2 3 2 2 3 6 1 5 2 4 2 6 6 2 1
[49] 2 2 4 6 2 6 5 5 4 6 3 2 1 2 3 4 1 6 5 3 1 4 5 5 5 4 3 1 3 3 6 6 5 2 4 6 6 6 4 2 5 6 4 5 1 1 6 6    
[97] 5 6 2 1 1 5 5 1 2 4 3 6 4 5 2 4 1 1 2 3 4 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 3 2 3 5 4 1 1 2 3 2 3 1 2 5 4 4 2 2 6 3
[145] 2 6 1 4 3 5 6 1 5 3 2 3 5 2 4 4 5 5 6 6 4 4 5 2 3 4 1 4 2 1 1 1 5 4 1 3 6 2 6 5 5 1 4 2 4 2 2 1
[193] 1 4 5 2 1 1 3 5
```

Above is a vector, whose dimension is 200. How to turn this into a vector `x` in R? It's tedious if I change it manually.

Another variable is:

```r
[1] "L" "L" "L" "L" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F"
[25] "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "L" "L" "L" "F"
[49] "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F"
[73] "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F"
[97] "F" "L" "L" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F"
[121] "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F"
[145] "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F"
[169] "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F"
[193] "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F"
```

Comment: Just a few seconds with a text editor and find and replace function

Comment: what text editor?

Comment: How do you get the vector printed as shown in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste it into `Lines` as shown and then use `gsub` to remove the [...] portions and finally `scan` it in.

```
Lines <- "
[1] 1 6 6 6 1 6 5 1 5 1 1 6 4 5 5 3 6 3 4 4 3 4 3 1 5 5 6 2 4 3 6 6 2 2 3 2 2 3 6 1 5 2 4 2 6 6 2 1
[49] 2 2 4 6 2 6 5 5 4 6 3 2 1 2 3 4 1 6 5 3 1 4 5 5 5 4 3 1 3 3 6 6 5 2 4 6 6 6 4 2 5 6 4 5 1 1 6 6
[97] 5 6 2 1 1 5 5 1 2 4 3 6 4 5 2 4 1 1 2 3 4 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 3 2 3 5 4 1 1 2 3 2 3 1 2 5 4 4 2 2 6 3
[145] 2 6 1 4 3 5 6 1 5 3 2 3 5 2 4 4 5 5 6 6 4 4 5 2 3 4 1 4 2 1 1 1 5 4 1 3 6 2 6 5 5 1 4 2 4 2 2 1
[193] 1 4 5 2 1 1 3 5
"

v <- scan(text = gsub("\\[\\d+\\]", "", Lines), quiet = TRUE)
length(v)
## [1] 200
```

Another approach using the same input is to `scan` it in as character strings and then use `grep` to remove the [...] parts and convert what remains to numeric.

```
sc <- scan(text = Lines, what = "", quiet = TRUE)
v <- as.numeric(grep("[", sc, fixed = TRUE, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE))
length(v)
## [1] 200
```

Here is the output from `dput(v)`

```
v <- 
c(1, 6, 6, 6, 1, 6, 5, 1, 5, 1, 1, 6, 4, 5, 5, 3, 6, 3, 4, 4, 
3, 4, 3, 1, 5, 5, 6, 2, 4, 3, 6, 6, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 6, 1, 5, 
2, 4, 2, 6, 6, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 2, 6, 5, 5, 4, 6, 3, 2, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 1, 6, 5, 3, 1, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 1, 3, 3, 6, 6, 5, 2, 4, 
6, 6, 6, 4, 2, 5, 6, 4, 5, 1, 1, 6, 6, 5, 6, 2, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 
2, 4, 3, 6, 4, 5, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 
2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 6, 3, 2, 6, 
1, 4, 3, 5, 6, 1, 5, 3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 4, 4, 5, 
2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 4, 1, 3, 6, 2, 6, 5, 5, 1, 4, 2, 
4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 5, 2, 1, 1, 3, 5)
```

### Second example

```
Lines2 <- '
[1] "L" "L" "L" "L" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F"
[25] "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "L" "L" "L" "F"
[49] "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F"
[73] "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F"
[97] "F" "L" "L" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F"
[121] "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F"
[145] "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F"
[169] "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F"
[193] "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F"
'

sc <- scan(text = Lines2, what = "", quiet = TRUE)
v2 <- grep("[", sc, fixed = TRUE, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
```

Here is the output from `dput(v2)`

```
v2 <-
c("L", "L", "L", "L", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "L", "L", "L", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "L", "L", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F")
```

Comment: But I cannot do this variable:

Comment: I have another variable. Please see my question. Thanks

Comment: I cannot run Lines <- "" This cannot be used in my second variable. R gives me incorrect message.

Comment: I have added code for t he second example at the end.